# How to install a Windows 8 App Without Submitting to Store

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

For a customer I need a to present our Windows 8 Metro App. When I deploy my solution or project, I get a exe but I can't install it. I get a MessageError, that I can only start the exe in a app container.

How can I create a version of my application to give it to my customer without loading it up to the Microsoft Store?

Comment: how come this is marked as off-topic???

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the PowerShell cmdlet [add-appxpackage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856048.aspx). For example:

```
add-appxpackage C:\myapp.appx
```

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2012/04/03/installing-enterprise-metro-apps-without-using-microsoft-store.aspx for more info.

Comment: How do i get .appx package ?

Comment: @smitalm If you create a Windows Store app under Visual Studio 2012, it will produce a .appx file. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446593(v=vs.85).aspx for more information on Windows Store apps in general.

Comment: Thank you, i already solved it. Here is how i got .appx package: Visual Studio 2012 -> Project -> Store -> Create app packages. I copied generated package to my Windows 8 tablet. In generated folder, there was 'Add-AppDevPackage.ps1' PowerShell script, which executed on tablet, and app was installed. During the process i needed administrator privileges, and my Windows Live Developer credentials.

Comment: is it possible ***silent installation*** in another machine?

Comment: In my case it throws an error about root certificate. I'm on Windows 8.1 Embedded.