# Can I distribute a Windows 8 Modern UI App without using the Store?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want to know if I can distribute a copy of a Windows 8 App using some form of package file, avoiding the need to get it from the Store. I want to target average users, not developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're targeting end users, i.e. consumers, then the answer would be no. I don't even see the advantage of bypassing the store in this case, since it only brings you a larger potential market for your application.

Sideloading of applications (the name used for installing them without publishing to the store) is supported only for the enterprise scenario to allow companies to install their own line of business applications which they don't want to publish in the store. There are [multiple requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10265361/197913) for this to work which are not feasible for individual end users.

That being said, nothing prevents you from creating the appx package (Project > Store > Create App Packages... menu in Visual Studio) and distribute it to your users. Along wih the package a PowerShell script is generated (`Add-AppDevPackage.ps1`) which takes care of installing the application on another machine, including installing the certificate and obtaining the deceloper license (for which he will need a Live account). The user will require administrative privileges to run the script. And he will have to renew the developer licence every 30 day for the app to continue working. Because of all that this process is really only suitable for a small number of users who can test your app before you submit it to the store.

Comment: I know that this is not the goal of this question, but is it easy for an average user to acomplish the installation process you describe (specially obtain a developer license)? I might create an App for some non-IT friends of mine.

Comment: @DanielSan It's not all that easy for a non-IT person. He needs to be able to run PowerShell as an admin and allow it to run scripts (`Set-ExecutionPolicy`). The script leads him from there on. And then every 30 days he needs to renew the licence, i.e. run `Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration` and follow the wizard. It's best you try it yourself on a clean machine in a VM and you'll see.

Answer (score 2):

I found the link below as an answer to a previous question.  It seems that you could easily install it using the temp folder and NSIS.

[How to install a Windows 8 App Without Submitting to Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512196/how-to-install-a-windows-8-app-without-submitting-to-store)

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Store is exactly the mechanism you'd want to use to target average users; it's the place they will go to discover and install new applications.

Technically, you can sideload applications; however, [that mechanism](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx#SideloadingRequirements) is for distributing line-of-business applications within an enterprise.  You can also install an application package directly on an end-user machine, but that will require a developer license on that machine, and that's explicitly contrary to your goals.